# Tastypie ModelResource fields based on methods

Tags: django-models, tastypie

So Tastypie automatically generates the fields based on the fields of your Django Model (if you use ModelResource). I would like to use some methods from my Model as fields in the Resource. Is there a good way to do this in Tastypie? I know it's possible to do it using `hydrate` but that seems a bit hackish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class UserCharField(ModelResource):
    stuff = fields.CharField(attribute='get_stuff_method', readonly=True)

class Meta:
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```